# Why does the Cisco SRE-V install fail to download the package file?

Tags: cisco, router

When installing the SRE-V software on one of my SRE modules in a Cisco 2911, it keeps failing to download the final files after loading the Linux kernel.

These are the interface configs from the router:

```
interface SM1/0
 ip address 192.168.201.1 255.255.255.0
 service-module ip address 192.168.201.2 255.255.255.0
 service-module ip default-gateway 192.168.201.1
interface SM1/1
 description Internal switch interface connected to Service Module
 switchport mode trunk
 no ip address
```

It is connected to my laptop running Python's SimpleHTTPServer via another 2911. Routing on both routers is setup so my local subnet can reach the SM1/0 IPs.

The router loads the installer and launches it without issue:

```
Router#service-module sm1/0 install url http://172.21.49.155:8000/sre-v-k9-r.SPA.smv.2.0.1.pkg   
Proceed with installation? [no]: yes
Loading http://172.21.49.155:8000/sre-v-k9-r.SPA.smv.2.0.1.pkg.install.sre !
Service module installation
ios_version     15.2(4)M2,
ios_image   c2900-universalk9-mz
pkg_name    sre-v-k9-r.SPA.smv.2.0.1.pkg
key_file    sre-v-k9-r.SPA.smv.2.0.1.key
helper_file     sre-v-installer.SPA.smv.2.0.1
pid         SM-SRE-900-K9

Check target platform capabilities
cpu      1865
Please select disk configuration (-1 = nonraid, 0 = raid0, 1 = raid1 ) [-1]: 1
Resource check completed successfully. Proceeding to Install ...

Router#
```

When monitoring the SRE session, it downloads and launches the kernel:

```
Initializing memory #1. Please wait...




Initializing memory #2. Please wait...


This may take a minute....


 Serial ATA Port 0 : Hitachi HTE545050B9A300                 
 Serial ATA Port 1 : Hitachi HTE545050B9A300                 
DDR Memory 8192 MB detected 
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     L9400  @ 1.86GHz
BIOS SM 3.52.8,  BIOS Build date: 02/08/2011

Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     L9400  @ 1.86GHz
BIOS SM 3.52.8,  BIOS Build date: 02/08/2011
System now booting...


Please wait...  

Please press P to select Primary Boot Loader ...   
          or S to select Secondary Boot Loader ...   
          or wait to boot from default configuration ...   

.......................................................................................................
Now booting from primary boot loader (Default)....  


Authenticating boot loader....   


Primary Boot Loader Authenticated - booting....   

boot params not set.

Updating flash with bootloader configuration.
Please wait ................... done.


Please enter '***' to change boot configuration: 

Detect and Initialize network device


Backup current platform configurations....

Updating flash with bootloader configuration.
Please wait ................... done.

SRE step 1 - SM registration...
Finding (hd1,3)/296e03bc-3236-4a68-a178-688e56400a1e, failed
Local install not supported

SRE step 2 - SM requests key file info...

SRE step 3 - SM stores registration info... 

Updating flash with bootloader configuration.
Please wait ................... done.

SRE step 4 - SM downloads key-file...
Writing keyfile to flash Size 916
writing complete.

Updating flash with bootloader configuration.
Please wait ................... done.

Erasing Post config Flash

SRE step 5 - SM requests installer info...

SRE step 6 - SM stores installer info...

Updating flash with bootloader configuration.
Please wait ................... done.

SRE step 7 - SM now downloads installer
| done.

SRE step 8 - SM requests tcl header file info...

SRE step 9 - SM now downloads the tcl header file
TCL header file downloaded completely size: 698

SRE step 10 - SM requests tcl file info...

SRE step 11 - SM now downloads the tcl file
TCL file downloaded completely size: 6520

SRE step 12 - SM now boots Installer
Verifying ... done.
Starting Kernel.

Platform: sm
INIT: version 2.86 booting
mounting proc fs ...
mounting sys fs ...
mounting /dev/shm tmpfs ...
kernel.sem = 1900 4000 32 100
vm.overcommit_memory = 1


        Welcome to Cisco Service Engine

Setting the system time from hardware clock

********** rc.aesop ****************
Populating resource values from /etc/sm_rsrc_file
Populating resource values from /etc/default_rsrc_file
Populating resource values from /usr/etc/products/galactica/default_rsrc_file
Populating resource values from /usr/etc/products/galactica/sm_rsrc_file
==> Management interface is eth0
==> Management interface is eth0
IOS IP Address Registration complete.
```

The routing table is correct and I can ping the SM's IP on eth0:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.201.0   *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
default         192.168.201.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
SM-SRE-900-K9 is in IDE mode
```

But the final download fails:

```
INIT: Entering runlevel: 2
********** rc.post_install ****************

Changing owners and file permissions.
Change owners and permissions complete.
INIT: Switching to runlevel: 4
INIT: Sending processes the TERM signal
STARTED: dwnldr_startup.sh
sre_type=  1
    Welcome to Cisco Systems Service Engine Helper Software
userinput=  disk-cfg-mode=raid1

Downloading http sre-v-k9-r.SPA.smv.2.0.1.pkg

SM1/0 is reset due to 
 Can not download sre-v-k9-r.SPA.smv.2.0.1.pkg 
error code 0 : error type 'couldn't connect to host'.


Error: Download error  
 Can not download sre-v-k9-r.SPA.smv.2.0.1.pkg 
error code 0 : error type 'couldn't connect to host'
Unable to install. Please try again.
```

I tried many different configurations to make this work but none of them would get past this final download after loading the kernel. I even tried loading the WLC software package using the exact same setup... and it loaded without a hitch:

```
Router#service-module sm1/0 install url http://172.21.49.155:8000/AS_SMWLC_7_4_110_0.aes                                   
Proceed with installation? [no]: yes
Loading http://172.21.49.155:8000/AS_SMWLC_7_4_110_0.aes.install.sre Welcome to WLC installation checking resource requirements now
Resource check complete proceeding with installation

Router#
[Resuming connection 1 to 192.168.201.1 ... ]

Detect and Initialize network device




Initializing memory #1. Please wait...




Initializing memory #2. Please wait...


This may take a minute....


 Serial ATA Port 0 : Hitachi HTE545050B9A300                 
 Serial ATA Port 1 : Hitachi HTE545050B9A300                 
DDR Memory 8192 MB detected 
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     L9400  @ 1.86GHz
BIOS SM 3.52.8,  BIOS Build date: 02/08/2011

Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     L9400  @ 1.86GHz
BIOS SM 3.52.8,  BIOS Build date: 02/08/2011
System now booting...


Please wait...  

Please press P to select Primary Boot Loader ...   
          or S to select Secondary Boot Loader ...   
          or wait to boot from default configuration ...   

.......................................................................................................
Now booting from primary boot loader....   


Authenticating boot loader....   


Primary Boot Loader Authenticated - booting....   



Please enter '***' to change boot configuration: 

Detect and Initialize network device


Backup current platform configurations....

SRE step 1 - SM registration...
Finding (hd1,3)/296e03bc-3236-4a68-a178-688e56400a1e, failed
Local install not supported

SRE step 2 - SM requests key file info...

SRE step 3 - SM stores registration info... 
SRE configuration keeps the same. No flash update needed!

SRE step 4 - SM downloads key-file...
Writing keyfile to flash Size 914
writing complete.

Updating flash with bootloader configuration.
Please wait .................... done.

Erasing Post config Flash

SRE step 5 - SM requests installer info...

SRE step 6 - SM stores installer info...

Updating flash with bootloader configuration.
Please wait .................... done.

SRE step 7 - SM now downloads installer
\ done.

SRE step 8 - SM requests tcl header file info...

SRE step 9 - SM now downloads the tcl header file
TCL header file downloaded completely size: 690

SRE step 10 - SM requests tcl file info...

SRE step 11 - SM now downloads the tcl file
TCL file downloaded completely size: 2819

SRE step 12 - SM now boots Installer

Verifying ... done.
Starting Kernel.

Platform: sm
INIT: version 2.86 booting
mounting proc fs ...
mounting sys fs ...
mounting /dev/shm tmpfs ...
kernel.sem = 1900 4000 32 100
vm.overcommit_memory = 1


        Welcome to Cisco Service Engine

Setting the system time from hardware clock

********** rc.aesop ****************
Populating resource values from /etc/sm_rsrc_file
Populating resource values from /etc/default_rsrc_file
==> Management interface is eth0
==> Management interface is eth0
IOS IP Address Registration complete.


Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.201.0   *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
default         192.168.201.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
Size of buff is: 65536
65536 bytes written
Valid License file not found: Using default values
INIT: Entering runlevel: 2
********** rc.post_install ****************

Changing owners and file permissions.
Change owners and permissions complete.
INIT: Switching to runlevel: 4
INIT: Sending processes the TERM signal
STARTED: dwnldr_startup.sh
You are about to repartition your compact flash, which will destroy all
existing data on it.

Do you want to Continue? [yn]:
Validating Flash Disk Geometry... 
Disk has a Valid partition table!
TotalCylinders = 1960
BytesPerCylinder = 1048576 
SafetyZoneBytes = 123312537 
SafetyZoneCylinders = 118 
TotalCylinders (after safety zone reduction) = 1842

WARNING:  About to repartition disk /dev/sdc as shown:
       /dev/sdc1    33 cylinders (33 Mb)
       /dev/sdc2*   9 cylinders (9 Mb)
       /dev/sdc3    1795 cylinders (1795 Mb)
       /dev/sdc4    5 cylinders (5 Mb)
Partitioning the flash disk... 
Disk /dev/sdc: 1960 cylinders, 64 heads, 32 sectors/track
Old situation:
Units = cylinders of 1048576 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1          4     899     896     917504    5  Extended
/dev/sdc2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdc3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdc4   *      0+      3       4-      4080   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdc5          4+    253     250-    255984    6  FAT16
/dev/sdc6        254+    503     250-    255984    6  FAT16
/dev/sdc7        504+    613     110-    112624   fc  Unknown
/dev/sdc8        614+    899     286-    292848    6  FAT16
New situation:
Units = cylinders of 1048576 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1          0+     32      33-     33791+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2   *     33      41       9       9216   83  Linux
/dev/sdc3         42    1836    1795    1838080   83  Linux
/dev/sdc4       1837    1841       5       5120   83  Linux
Successfully wrote the new partition table

Re-reading the partition table ...

Creating the filesystems... 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  299k  100  299k    0     0  1524k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 5542k
Read 306504 bytes from sm_bl

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  2  112M    2 3088k    0     0  3505k      0  0:00:32 --:--:--  0:00:32 3869k
100  112M  100  112M    0     0  8510k      0  0:00:13  0:00:13 --:--:-- 9247k.
Executing Product Check TLV.
Executing Version Built TLV.
Warning: Unknown TLV ignored.
Warning: Unknown TLV code 8 - ignored.
Executing init script.
Executing backup script.

Executing install_bootloader script.
Writing new RTOS to flash disk.
Executing install_rtos script.
Writing new Code to flash disk.
Executing install_code script.
Writing new Emergency Bootloader to flash disk.
Writing new Emergency Bootloader RTOS to flash disk.
Writing new Emergency Version to flash disk.
Writing new AP Image Bundle to flash disk.
Executing fini script.

Install successful on SM1/0. Please wait for module to reset before next operation.
```

It doesn't make sense to me that it cannot reach my laptop to download the final file after it has already downloaded the kernel and other files from my laptop successfully. On top of that, the WLC package works flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the SRE-V 2.0.1 package scripts. The `dwnldr_startup.sh` script in this package doesn't support using a different port for the download. While the same script from the WLC package does support using a different port.

When switching the HTTP server hosting the files to port 80, the SRE-V 2.0.1 package will install fine.

```
STARTED: dwnldr_startup.sh
sre_type=  1
    Welcome to Cisco Systems Service Engine Helper Software
userinput=  disk-cfg-mode=raid1

Downloading http sre-v-k9-r.SPA.smv.2.0.1.pkg
Bytes downloaded :  14001 

Validating package signature ... done
 - Parsing package manifest files... complete.
No installed manifests found.
 - Checking Package dependencies... complete.
 - Checking Manifest dependencies for subsystems in the install candidate list...
```

(removed excess output)

```
EXITED: dwnldr_startup.sh exit status 137
Process shutdown complete.
starting_phase:
install_files.sh /mnt/dwnld/.work_order
Remove: /mivmdk//dwnld/scripts
. rbcp_install_status_msg_for
Install successful on SM1/0. Please wait for module to reset before next operation.
```